# Remover penultimo caracter de uma string

Tags: delphi, memo

Possuo uma aplicação que ao clicar nos `labels` um `edit` recebe as suas `caption` da seguinte forma:

```
Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + TLabel(Sender).caption+ ' ';
```

Após isso clico em ok, e essa informação passa a um `memo`.
Porem o problema aparece agora ao clicar no ok esse código envia os dados ao `memo`:

```
Memo1.Lines.add('    '+'if'+' '+ cond1+':');
```

O `memo` recebe o seguinte valor por exemplo:

```
    if dose > 0 :
```

Podem reparar que após o 0 existe um espaço, gostaria de remover ele para que ficasse da seguinte forma:

```
    if dose > 0:
```

Comment: Tente usar as funcções TrimLeft, TrimRight ou Trim, para remover os espaços em branco.

Comment: não quero remover todos os espaços em brancos apenas o que indiquei na pergunta

Comment: Veja se pode ajudar a você adaptar na sua pergunta. http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/deletar-ultimo-caracter-de-uma-string/158822

Comment: Se seu if tivesse algo como `if dose > 01:` ele teria que retirar o 1?

Comment: o TrimLeft ou TrimRight nao remove todos os espaços em branco da string.

Comment: Obrigado @RBoschini a função TrimRight resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tente usar da seguinte forma

```
var tamanho : integer;
begin
  if trim(edit1.text) <> '' then  // valida se o edit esta preenchido
  begin
     tamanho := Length(edit1.Text);   // pega o tamanho da variavel
     if copy(edit1.Text,tamanho-1,tamanho) = ' ' then  // verifica se é espaço nulo
        Memo1.Lines.add(deletechar(' ',edit1.text));
  end;
end;

function DeleteChar(Ch: Char; S: string): string;   // deleta o caracter da variavel na possição informada antes...
var Posicao: integer;
begin
   Posicao := tamanho-1;
   Delete(S,Posicao, 1);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem varias formas de o fazer esta é uma delas, basta para isso criar a seguinte function:

```
function TfrmMain.GetResult(val1: String): String;
var val2, val3: String;
begin
  val2 := copy(val1, 1,  Length(val1) - 2);
  val3 := copy(val1, Length(val1),  1);

  Result := val2 + val3;
end;
```

E vai ser necessário no evento de um botão por exemplo chamar a function:

```
procedure TfrmMain.BtnGetResultClick(Sender: TObject);
var val1: String;
begin
  val1 := 'if dose > 0 :';
  Memo1.Lines.Add(GetResult(val1));
end;
```